# Write lines longer than 80 chars in output file [Python]

Tags: python, file-io, numpy

I've got a pretty basic question. I'm using Python to calculate an n×12 vector

```
y = numpy.array([V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10,V11,V12])
```

which I append after each loop calculation.

My problem is that when I try to save it to a file or print it
Python automatically breaks the result in three lines as my
output usually exceeds 200 chars. Is there a way to supress 
this 80 char/line behavior? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some code. And are you sure that the file actually contains linebreaks and it's not your terminal or whatever you use to view it?

Comment: Ok...it's quite complicated to show you how I get y but take my word for it; it's a one line vector with 12 elements and more than 80 chars. What matters is that I open a file, do

f.write(str(y[:,0]).replace('[','').replace(']', '  ')+'\t'+str(y[:,1]).replace('[','').replace(']', '  ')+.....)

and then close it. My output (just numbers) is shown in 3 lines.

Comment: p.s. Don't know whether it makes a difference but I'm using IDLE.

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`numpy.savetxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to save an array to a text file while controlling the formatting.  To print it to the screen, you have different options to control the linewidth.  One would be to call

```
numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)
```

to set the linewidth to a higher value.

Comment: For me, using the linewidth parameter for set_printoptions() has just no effect at all when printing a matrix to the console (the output is still formatted with the '...' ellipses (in both dimensions)). What are the other options?

Comment: @StefanQ The ellipsis has nothing to do with the current set line width.  By default, the number of entries included in the representation is limited.  This can probably be changed with `set_printoptions()` as well.  Please refer to the documentation for details, or ask a separate question, since this is completely unrelated to this question here.