# Is there a way to change IPython's (numpy) line-wrapping?

Tags: python, command-line, numpy, ipython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write lines longer than 80 chars in output file [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286544/write-lines-longer-than-80-chars-in-output-file-python)

I'm trying to print matrices on the command-line that contain big values and the 80-char fixed column width is not sufficient to get a nice picture. I have a lot of wasted screen space that could probably help me.

Is there a way to disable the line wrapping seemingly imposed by either Python or IPython? How?

EDIT: Yes, I am using numpy, so that's where it comes from. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using numpy? If so, use `numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=140)` or whatever value you think is appropriate. See the link.

Comment: @Sven - Beat me to it, though I didn't realize it when I posted my answer.

Comment: @ulidtko, your comment should be an answer!